# redis-backed spring-session in wicket app, problem with ajax calls resulting in full page redirect

Tags: java, spring, redis, wicket

I'm trying to modify a wicket application to store the session in redis via spring-session.  The session is showing up in redis, but I've run into a problem that whenever the application makes a standard wicket ajax call, the response from wicket includes an Ajax-Location header that is interpreted by wicket-ajax-jquery.js triggering a page redirect.  But this only happens AFTER the first ajax call has been successful.  For example, the first ajax call may look like this:

http://host:port/context/help/admin?0-1.IBehaviorListener.0-smartTable-tableArea-records-0-row-detailToggleCell-detailToggleLink&_=1636756805561

and the response headers do NOT include Ajax-Location.  And then later, the next ajax call may look like this:

http://host:port/context/help/admin?1-1.IBehaviorListener.0-smartTable-tableArea-records-0-row-detailToggleCell-detailToggleLink&_=1636756906417

But the response header now includes this:

`Ajax-Location: ./admin?2`

and instead of just doing the ajax update to the page, the entire page redirects to the URL specified in that header because of code in src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/res/js/wicket-ajax-jquery.js

Digging down into the wicket-core code using the debugger, consider this where it doesn't produce the Ajax-Location header and works properly:

```
Step completed: "thread=ba6f07:3", org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(), line=197 bci=169
ba6f07:3[1] print canCallListenerInterfaceAfterExpiry
 canCallListenerInterfaceAfterExpiry = false
ba6f07:3[1] print freshPage
 freshPage = false
ba6f07:3[1] print isStateless
 isStateless = false
ba6f07:3[1] print component
 component = "[AjaxLink [Component id = detailToggleLink]]"
```

and then compare with this where it DOES produce an Ajax-Location header and doesn't work properly:

```
Breakpoint hit: "thread=ba6f07:7", org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(), line=197 bci=169
ba6f07:7[1] print canCallListenerInterfaceAfterExpiry
 canCallListenerInterfaceAfterExpiry = false
ba6f07:7[1] print freshPage
 freshPage = true
ba6f07:7[1] print isStateless
 isStateless = false
ba6f07:7[1] print component
 component = null
```

The difference being that when it doesn't work, freshPage is true and component is null.

*Note: this pattern is fully functional in another similar application that I have and I’ve spent some time comparing the two.  Clearly, something is missing from the original application in the app that I’m working on but I haven’t been able to identify it yet.*

My redis http session config class looks like this:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.CookieHttpSessionStrategy;
import org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer;

@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class MyRedisHttpSessionConfig extends RedisHttpSessionConfiguration
{
  private JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init()
  {
    CookieHttpSessionStrategy strategy = new CookieHttpSessionStrategy();
    DefaultCookieSerializer cookieSerializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    cookieSerializer.setCookieName( "SESSION" );
    strategy.setCookieSerializer(cookieSerializer);
    setHttpSessionStrategy( strategy );
  }
  
  @Bean
  public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws Exception
  {
    return connectionFactory;
  }

  public void setConnectionFactory( JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory )
  {
    this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
  }

}
```

my web.xml has this:

```
...
  <filter>
    <filter-name>requestLoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>myApplicationWicketFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
      <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>filterMappingUrlPattern</param-name>
      <param-value>/*</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
...
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping> 
...
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ariesApplicationWicketFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
...
```

and my spring beans config file has this:

```
...
<!-- The RedisHttpSessionConfiguration creates an http Filter bean with name "springSessionRepositoryFilter" which is referenced in web.xml -->
  <context:annotation-config/>

  <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.ConfigureRedisAction.NO_OP"/>
  <bean class="MyRedisHttpSessionConfig">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="webTierRedisConnectionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="webTierRedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${service-tier:redisSentinelMasterName}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${service-tier:redisSentinelHostPortCsv}"/>
    <property name="usePool" value="true"/>
    <property name="poolConfig">
      <bean class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
        <property name="maxWaitMillis" value="5000"/>
        <property name="maxTotal" value="50"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="10"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
...
```

Ivy Dependencies include:

```
    <!-- these are for redis httpsession -->
    <dependency org="redis.clients" name="jedis" rev="2.8.1"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework.data" name="spring-data-redis" rev="1.7.4.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework.data" name="spring-data-keyvalue" rev="1.1.4.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework.session" name="spring-session" rev="1.2.2.RELEASE"/>
```

and wicket 7.5.0 and spring 4.2.8 stuff.

Anybody have any insights on what might be going on?  Why after putting the session into redis (which it is showing up there, I see it (via redis-cli and keys and dump commands), most ajax calls are triggering full page redirects due to response headers from the ajax call including Ajax-Location?

Comment: Does the application work correctly if you use the default session store (HttpSession+DiskPageStore) ? If it works then the problem must be in the (Spring) Redis integration. If it still redirects to a new page then we can exclude Redis, so it is either Wicket or your application.

Comment: Yes, the app works correctly with the default session store, and you make a good point that that means the problem is the spring-session redis integration.

Comment: Wicket stores the page's data with a key of sessionId+pageId and value of the serialized page (i.e. as bytes). In case of Ajax requests the pageId does not change and Wicket overrides the old entry in the store. Look in this direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a custom org.apache.wicket.IPageManagerProvider implementation which needed to be replaced with a version that was compatible with redis.